# mp3-duration package for streams?

Tags: node.js, npm, stream, mp3

Did anyone start making an npm package like `mp3-duration` for streams? I would like to do something like this:

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
const durationSec = await getAudioDurationInSeconds(stream);
```

Comment: Are you doing this in Node.js, or in the browser?  You've tagged this as HTML5 audio, but provided a Node.js example, so it isn't clear.

Comment: In Node.js. I didn't find any better tag.

Comment: Try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/music-metadata

Comment: @Avraham Ah, that looks exactly like what I need.